# PHP skips check and insert data even if it already exists

Tags: php, mysql, insert, verify

I have having a difficult time trying to determine if an email exists in my database table. Currently, it seems to skip the check and insert the email  data to the db. It does this even if the email exists in the database.

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong? I've tried a number of ways, but so far all of them "ignore" the verification step and inserts the duplicate data

Here is my code:

```
 <?php
 $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","usr1","123456%%","db1");
 // Check conn
 if (mysqli_connect_errno())
   {
   echo "Deu merda ao conectar ao MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
   }

 //query to insert data to db
 $sql="INSERT INTO workshops (nome, email, curso, telefone, semestre, workshop)
      VALUES('$_POST[nome]','$_POST[email]','$_POST[curso]','$_POST[telefone]','$_POST[semestre]'     ,'$_POST[workshop]')";

 //stores email in a var
 $email = $_POST['email'];

 //query to look up for the email
 $query = mysqli_query("SELECT `email` FROM `workshops` WHERE `email` = '$email'");

 //runs $query to see if it finds any result
 if(mysqli_num_rows($query) > 0) {
 echo 'Email already registered'.mysqli_error();
 mysqli_close($con);

 } else {
mysqli_query($con,$sql);
echo "We received your request, thank you!";

//blah blah blah email in portuguese
$assunto = "Confirmaçãoao de inscrição";
$mensagem = "<h1>Obrigado!</h1><br>Recebemos sua inscrição no workshop" .      $_POST['workshop'] . ". <br> Iremos entrar em contato em breve para confirmar sua presença.";
    $from = "contato@mult13.com";
$headers = "From:". $from;
mail($_POST['email'], $assunto, $mensagem, $headers);
mysqli_close($con);
 }
 ?>
```

Comment: Your logic is wrong. You are UPDATEing the database THEN checking if the email exists. It should be the other way round. Check if the email exists then UPDATE the database if it doesn't.

Comment: Trying this, updating my answer in 5 minutes. I hope it works, thanks!

Still not working, or i don't know how to change the order. How do i do this?

Comment: actully you are right and @jeff is mistaken, the insert is defined in the $sql string, before the check, but not run there. cn you add your form to the code above

Comment: Dam it. Should have put my glasses on :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `mysqli_query` you are using to check if the email exists needs a reference to the mysql connection.

Change this line:

```
//query to look up for the email
$query = mysqli_query("SELECT `email` FROM `workshops` WHERE `email` = '$email'");
```

to this:

```
//query to look up for the email
$query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT `email` FROM `workshops` WHERE `email` = '$email'");
```

Comment: Thanks Sunnefa, it worked! Can't belive i couldn't see it, i might need some more coffee :o

Comment: I'm surprised you didn't get an error. Make sure you have error reporting enabled.